# What is the best way to backup a django project?

Tags: django, backup

I maintain a couple of low-traffic sites that have reasonable user uploaded media files and semi big databases. My goal is to backup all the data that is not under version control in a central place.

#### My current approach

At the moment I use a nightly cronjob that uses `dumpdata` to dump all the DB content into JSON files in a subdirectory of the project. The media uploads is already in the project directory (in `media`).

After the DB is dumped, the files are copied with `rdiff-backup` (makes an incremental backup) into another location. I then download the rdiff-backup directory on a regular basis with `rsync` to store a local copy.

---

#### Your Ideas?

What do you use to backup your data? Please post your backup solution - if you only have a few hits per day on your site or if you maintain a high traffic one with shareded databases and multiple fileservers :)

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I've found this solution called [Django-Backup](https://github.com/django-backup/django-backup) and has worked for me. You can even combine the task of backing up the databases or media files with a cronjob.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

My backup solution works the following way:

1. Every night, dump the data to a separate directory. I prefer to keep data dump directory distinct from the project directory (one reason being that project directory changes with every code deployment).
2. Run a job to upload the data to my Amazon S3 account and another location using `rsync`.
3. Send me an email with the log.

To restore a backup locally I use a script to download the data from S3 and upload it locally.

Comment: How do you cope up with the increasing backup sizes/?